# Xceed WPF Datagrid Printing fixed column on every page

Tags: wpf, datagrid, printing, xceed

I have a grid with one fixed column and many other columns. When i do a print (datagrid.Print()) on the second page i have the columns that would not fit onto the first page but without the fixed column (which is only printed on the first). I would like to repeat the fixed column on every page i print as it is the key to the data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PrintTableView you can set the FixedColumnCount. e.g

```
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.PrintView>
            <xcdg:PrintTableView
                          IsAlternatingRowStyleEnabled="True"
                          FixedColumnCount="1" >...
```

Comment: thanks daniel, you just saved us $900, I wasn't getting any replies on the xceed forum and we were thinking about resigning up for supprt as we have let it lapse.